# Resolution of Time object in before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a `before_save` callback in my rails model, and it looks like

```
before_save do 
  self.time_parameter = Time.zone.now.utc
end
```

Will the time object be resolved once in the same way as a `scope` method? Or will it correctly use the current time every time the model is saved?

Comment: create a few records and then look at the values saved?  won't that answer your question?

Comment: Well it would, but the core question really more to do with when time resolves, not this individual instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrapped in a block (like a method) so it will be resolved each time the `before_save` is triggered

Comment: Is wrapped in a block the prevailing rule of thumb for determining this?